# How to debug a dynamic library

Tags: c++, xcode, lldb

I've got a XCode workspace.

This workspace holds the main target (Swift) and a target with a dynamic library embedded in a framework.

The entry of the framework is a wrapper class written in Objective-C++. The dynamic library has been written in C++.

The project seems to compile and link fine, but when I execute one its methods, it throws me back an error I would like to debug.

I tried stepping in with the debugger but then I only get int the stack. I can try to follow the stack but I can't print any variables, it only shows the method names that have been called.

I also tried an exception breakpoint, but it only stops in the Objective-C++ wrapper layer.

Is there any way to debug the insides of the dynamic library with XCode or LLDB?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can:  Debug > Debug Workflow > **Always Show Disassembly**, and then you may want to use Debug > **Step Over Instruction** and Debug > **Step Into Instruction**

Comment: That's kind of the way I was doing it, but it would take me ages to debug.
I was thinking more of setting a breakpoint at a particular line in the cpp source file compile into the library, for example.

Comment: You can do that as well, but it requires that you have the source file of the library.

Comment: Did you build the C++ part of the framework?  If you didn't then you don't have debug info for that part, and disassembly is pretty much the best you can do.  If you did build the framework, then debugging it should "just work".  It sounds like either you didn't build it, or it was built w/o debug information or it got stripped before you set about to debug it.

Comment: Nop, the C++ part is inside of the dynamic library which is in the framework. I was thinking if it's possible to tell XCode: look about this library that you are using, if you want to show where each symbol comes from what file and line file, the source code is here ( and point in an external location to the project where the source code is ).

Maybe like ` gdb's dir`?

Comment: gdb's `dir` just tells gdb about other places to look for source files, in case they aren't where the debug info says they are.  But the source files by themselves can't provide the mapping from lines -> instructions as they have no way of knowing how the binary was built.  You need the debug info for that.  Similarly, if symbols have been stripped, lldb has no way to reconstruct them except debug info.  If you want to do symbolic debugging of this library you need to either build it locally, or get a dSYM with debug info from whoever provided the library.